# bitwise operator variations in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operators

I read C++ provides additional operators to the usual &,|, and ! which are "and","or" and "not" respectively, plus they come with automatic short circuiting properties where applicable.

I would like to use these operators in my code but the compiler interprets them as identifiers and throws an error.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition with SP1. How do I activate these operators to use in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have the '`and`', '`or`', '`xor`', etc keyword versions of the operators made available in MSVC++ then you either have to use the '`/Za`' option to disable extensions or you have to include `iso646.h`.

Comment: Having made your day, I'd strongly suggest avoiding using the 'alternative tokens' for the operators. I think that most C++ programmers reading the code would prefer to see the usual operators.

Comment: Well then, I think it is time for a change. We are supposed to get more descriptive with our variable names and the like right (i bet you'd scream if you saw int i = 3.142;). the token "and" and more descriptive in my opinion than & or &&

Comment: Personally, I don't think it helps understanding to use the words instead of the symbols. You'll still have to get a handle on the old style to read code other people write. And adding the choice to C++ doesn't add it to C, Java, C#, Objective-C, or JavaScript. And either way, you're going to have to get "bitwise" and "logical" straight or fall into some really hard-to-debug situations.

Comment: I understand that it's a matter of opinion or style, but I think that people are used to the punctuation-style tokens and would find the keyword variants something they have to 'stop and think about'. I'm currently working a project where the existing code mostly uses macros for the logical operators (AND, OR, NEQ, etc), and I must say I don't like it at all...  I believe the alternative keyword tokens were provided mostly to aid programmers with non-US keyboards that didn't always have the correct punctuation characters, not an attempt to make them more readable (just more type-able).

Comment: A benefit to using the symbol style is that it is easy to distinguish between operators and variables when scanning code. It's a lot harder when everything is alphanumeric text.

Comment: @emdduley, I agree with that for C-based languages. However, Ruby and Python use the words and manage to be readable. I think Perl gives you the choice.

Comment: I've come across this style a few times and never liked it. Makes it difficult to tell whether the original writer intended logical or bitwise operations.

Comment: A different color for these tokens would solve all the issues you guys are complaining about. I must admit, using theses tokens with their colors indistinguishable from the actual code makes it a bit difficult to spot them. When they are implemented in VC++ and become keywords the different coloration (from black to blue) should make things easier.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional C++ spelling [*] (just like in C) is `&&` for "logical", short-circuit *and*, `||` for "logical", short-circuit *or*. `!` is "logical" *not* (of course it doesn't short-circuit: what ever would that **mean**?!-).  The bitwise versions are `&`, `|`, `~`.

According to the C++ standard, the spellings you like (`and`, `or`, and so on) should also be implemented, but apparently popular compilers disobey that rule. However you should be able to `#include <ciso646>` or `#include <iso646.h>` to hack around that via macros -- see [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ciso646/), and if your favorite compiler is missing these header files, just create them the obvious way, i.e.,

```
#define and &&
#define or ||
```

and so on. (Kudos and gratitude to the commenters for making me research the issue better and find this out!)

Comment: Recent versions of the C++ standard include spellings such as "and" and "or".

Comment: @Greg good point, added a footnote on the likely future standard (albeit of, more or less, just "academic" interest at this point in time;-).

Comment: @ Alex: My bad, I didn't even notice those.Thanks for the correction.

Comment: 'and', 'bitor', 'or', 'xor', 'compl', 'bitand', 'and_eq', 'or_eq', 'xor_eq', 'not' and 'not_eq' are all valid alternative tokens for '&&', '|', '||', '^', '~', '&', '&=', '|=', '^=', '!' and '!=' respectively in the current standard (2003).

Comment: @Charles: So it it that VC++ does not implement these? Could you show me how to access them please

Comment: VC 2008 is not stricly compliant, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198402/missing-desired-features-in-visual-c/198671#198671

Comment: MS just makes me wonder sometimes... geez. Thanks Charles for the information. I guess I'll have to wait till 2010 with my fingers crossed hoping MS finally implement it or change my IDE.

Comment: The and, or, bitand etc. keywords are defined in the original 1998 C++ Standard - see section 2.4.